# Laravel whereNull and where not returning any results

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have something strange going on. I am trying to query with a `whereNull` and also a `where` statement. When i just use the `whereNull` it returns results, but as soon as I add the `where` statement, nothing gets returned even though there should be 2 results.

```
$user
    ->shoePurchases()
    ->whereNull('completed_at')
    ->where('status', '!=', 'failed')
    ->get();
```

The `shoePurchases` relationship is a simple hasMany

Comment: If you get the SQL query from this and run this on the database are results returned? Also whats shoePurchases() doing?

Comment: so there is a related record that is `null` for `completed_at` and also has `status <> 'failed'`?

Comment: could you please share the raw query of your eloquent builder using toSql()?
$user
    ->shoePurchases()
    ->whereNull('completed_at')
    ->where('status', '!=', 'failed')
    ->toSql();

Answer (score 0):

You can do these things in order to find the problem

Review the data: Ensure that there exist shoe purchases which are not marked as "failed" and are yet to be completed. To perform this check, execute the following query directly on your database:

```
SELECT * FROM shoe_purchases WHERE completed_at IS NULL AND status != 'failed';
```

Remove the where clause for the status and see if you get any results. This will help you determine if the issue is with the whereNull or the where clause for the status.

```
$user
    ->shoePurchases()
    ->whereNull('completed_at')
    ->get();
```

Use the orWhere method: Instead of using multiple where clauses, use the orWhere method to retrieve shoe purchases that are not completed or have a status other than "failed".

```
$user
    ->shoePurchases()
    ->where(function($query) {
        $query->whereNull('completed_at')
              ->orWhere('status', '!=', 'failed');
    })
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I guess All purchases with status != 'failed' have completed_at not null